# value build is not a member of com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder

Tags: scala, metrics

I'm not sure why I get following error:

```
error: value build is not a member of com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder[String,com.codahale.metrics.Metric]
[INFO] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value build'?
[INFO]       .build[String, Metric]
[INFO]        ^

CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .maximumSize(maximumSize)
  .expireAfterWrite(expireAfterWriteMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  .asInstanceOf[CacheBuilder[String, Metric]]
  .build[String, Metric]()
  .asMap()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

fixed it

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1095